# What are my options to trick a player on one-on-one?

Tags: pro-evolution-soccer-2011

In Pro Evolution Soccer 2011 for Xbox 360, what are my options to trick/surpass a player on one-on-one while I have the ball and I'm on attack? What are the button combinations to perform these actions?

I'm playing in Regular and sometimes in Professional mode if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use feints.  Here is an excellent tutorial:

Outrunning in PES 2011 doesn't work that well, even when your player should be faster than the defender. They say they've fixed this in 2012.